# How to create listView from text file?

Tags: c#

I have a text file like this:

```
==
a
03/09
==
b
02/09
```

And I want to create a listView from the text file like this:

[image]

How can I do this in C#?

I've tried this code:

```
ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
var sectionCharacters = File.ReadLines("bdaylist.list")
                            .SkipWhile(s => s != "==") 
                            .Skip(1)                            
                            .Skip(2)
                            .ToList();
lvi.Text = sectionCharacters[1];
lvi.SubItems.Add(sectionCharacters[2]);
listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
```

but it only read *b* and *02/09*

Comment: StackOverflow works this way - you **try** to solve task on your own, and if you have some problems (error or unexpected results), then you give **problem description**, your current **code** and ask people to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var sectionCharacters = File.ReadLines("your_filepath_here").ToList();

//To remove '=='
sectionCharacters.Where(i => i.Trim() == "==").ToList()
                 .ForEach(item => sectionCharacters.Remove(item));

//To remove 'blank lines', if any
sectionCharacters.Where(i => i.Trim() == "").ToList()
                 .ForEach(item => sectionCharacters.Remove(item));

for (int i = 0; i < sectionCharacters.Count; i += 2)
{
    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
    lvi.Text = sectionCharacters[i];
    lvi.SubItems.Add(sectionCharacters[i + 1]);
    listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
}
```

Output:

[image]

PS: This is a simple listView to show the output. You might get the idea what to do with your listView having checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Skip(1) and Skip(2) which is ignoring your first 2 entries. You are also only adding one item to the list. You can change your linq as below, and check for the even number item in the collection to add both to the listview.

```
    var sectionCharacters = File.ReadAllLines("bdaylist.list").Where(s => s != "==").ToList();            

        for (int i = 0; i < sectionCharacters.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                var lvi = new ListViewItem { Text = sectionCharacters[i] };
                lvi.SubItems.Add(sectionCharacters[i + 1]);
                listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
            }
        }
```